# What was the "biggest" or the "greatest" task ever performed by MITS Altair 8800?

Tags: altair-8800

We know that computer is used for many things, to control many things, to do many jobs, as server, to control airplane traffic, and many things a computer can do. But I am curious about the MITS Altair 8800. As I read in many news or articles, that "computer" always said used by hobbyists. I have never read any article saying that that kind of computer used for special purpose, neither by a hobbyist nor by a company.

Imagine that one of the hobbyist used that Altair 8800 to do simple calculation such as "+, -, x, /", to control his/her room temperature, used for timer to turn on/off light at home, to water circulation of an aquarium, and so on. Then, what was the "biggest" or the greatest task ever performed by MITS Altair 8800?

Comment: Unless we have a better definition of "greatest" this question is answerable.

Comment: Does "greatest" mean "highest $ value of stuff connected"? Or "most newsworthy"? Or "part of most well known organization"? Just an arbitrary "cool stuff" list would be fun but impossible to "answer".

Comment: Hi Guys, you should not spend your time asking something trivial. You can easily distinct between a computer used to control home light and a computer to control traffic of an airport plane. Sometime is not easy to write it, that's why gave some example. All businessmen should not put a thing which is not robust to control such an expensive thing. Because of an expensive, than we call it "biggest" or "greatest". But, still I put it in quote as I realized that it is not easy to define. But let just use our common sense.

Comment: This is what you needed for Air Traffic Control https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9ih93tuH1k

Comment: Guy I knew in college ran a program on his Altair... When you held a cheap AM radio close enough to the computer, the EMI picked up by the radio sounded like a buzzy, nasty version of a recognizable tune. So, Um, how about "music player?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Altair is the first of a category of machines that gave rise to CP/M — you'd need to add more RAM, a disk drive, a serial port and a terminal but adding to the box was standard usage; the Altair is the originator of the S-100 bus.

With CP/M you have word processors like WordStar, spreadsheets like Super Calc, databases like dBase, programming environments like Turbo Pascal and more.

So an Altair may eventually have been used for mostly the same productivity tasks as MS-DOS.

Comment: Many definitely were used as cpm machines for office automation. I think OP is looking for "factory control" or "stage lights control" or "rocket launcher" or "TV title production" etc.

Comment: Rocket launcher?  The Altair may not have accomplished much, but one of its IMSAI clones armed with an acoustic coupler modem almost lead to the launching of a lot of rockets.  Er, well, okay, that was a movie.  But there's reason to believe it may have resulted in policy changes in real life.